# Why interrupt service routine cannot contain most system calls

Tags: unix, operating-system, interrupt, system-calls

This is one of guidelines when writing interrupt handler:
The handler can't call library routines that contain kernel calls except for InterruptDisable() ,InterruptEnable() , InterruptLock() , InterruptMask() , InterruptUnlock() , andInterruptUnmask() .
Why cannot contain sys calls?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9442579/968261) should give you an idea why.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What all cant be there in an Interrupt service routine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442463/what-all-cant-be-there-in-an-interrupt-service-routine)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is an interrupt can happen at any time; it could have happened while executing another system call which manipulates kernel data structures; therefore, this is needed to insure mutual exclusion. if you make a system call it might corrupt the data structures.